# how could I make a general formula for this pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trees

I am attempting to find a formula that describes the number of leaf nodes in a full binary tree of depth `k`, therefore nodes at a depth `<k` have exactly two children and the leaves are at depth K.

This gives me the following pattern.
A tree with 1 Node has 1 Leaf
A tree with 3 Nodes has 2 leaves
A tree with 7 Nodes has 4 leaves
A tree with 15 Nodes has 8 leaves
A tree with 31 Nodes has 16 leaves

I am trying to figure out a formula that tells the number of leaves given `N = Number of Nodes` but have not been able to figure it out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Have you spent at least 5 or 10 minutes trying to figure this out? If so, what did you try? Also, do you want to learn how to find the answer, or do you just want the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Add one to the number of nodes and compare it to the number of leaves. Do you see a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there exist $a$ and $b$ such that the number of leaves in a tree with $n$ nodes is $an+b$. Use two of the examples you've found already to find $a$ and $b$.

> A tree with $n$ nodes has $\frac{n+1}{2}$ leaves.
>  Equivalently, a tree with $2^k-1$ nodes has $2^{k-1}$ leaves.